# Topologies and Completions

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

In my tutorial today we looked at the following question in Atiyah-McDonald:

Let $\alpha_n : \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ be the injection of abelian groups given by $\alpha_n(1) = p^{n-1}$, and let $\alpha : A \to B$ be the direct sum of the $\alpha_n$. Show that the $p$-adic completion of $A$ is just $A$ but the completion of $A$ for the topology induced from the $p$-adic topology on $B$ is the direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Deduce that $p$-adic completion is not a right-exact functor on the category of all $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

The start of the solution that was given has confused me. The tutor started with: Since $pA =0$, the sequence $A/p^nA$ is $$\cdots A \xrightarrow{ \ \ \text{id} \ \ } A \xrightarrow{ \ \ \text{id} \ \ } A,$$ the coherent sequences of which are constant sequences $(a)$, yielding the obvious isomorphism $$\lim_{\longleftarrow} A/p^nA \cong A.$$

I don't understand any component of this part of the proof. How do we obtain such sequences, how do we then determine the coherent sequences and then how is the isomorphism obtained?

Comment: What is $A$ here?

Answer (score 1):

As $A:=\mathbb{Z}_p=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ it's easy to see that $pA=p\cdot \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}=0.$ So now let's consider the inverse system $$\cdots \to A/p^{n+1}A\to A/p^{n}A\to A/p^{n-1}A\to \cdots. $$ What's going on at each step? The ideal $p^{n+1}A$ is a sub-ideal of $p^{n}A$, and the map $A/p^{n+1}A\to A/p^{n}A$ takes an element $[m]_{\text{mod } p^{n+1}}\in A/p^{n+1}A$ to the element $[m]_{\text{mod } p^{n}}\in A/p^{n}A$. However, we can simplify this via some isomorphisms using the fact that $pA=0$. If $pA=0$ then as $p^{n}A\subseteq pA$ we must have $p^{n}A=0.$ So for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $A/p^n A\cong A$ and the isomorphism $A/p^n A \to A$ is $[m]_{\text{mod } p^{n}}\mapsto [m]_{\text{mod } p}.$ The maps $A/p^{n+1}A\to A/p^{n}A$ are then just $\text{id}_A\colon A\to A$. So that's the first part: we're reduced to the inverse system $$\cdots A \xrightarrow{ \ \ \text{id} \ \ } A \xrightarrow{ \ \ \text{id} \ \ } A.$$

Now we need to compute the coherent sequences to work out what the inverse limit $$\lim_{\longleftarrow} A/p^nA$$ really is. Recall that a coherent sequence $(a_n)$ has the properties $a_n\in A/p^n A$ and $a_n$ is the image of $a_{n+1}$ under the given maps. If we take some element $[m]_{\text{mod }p}\in A=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ as our element $a_0$, then we're forced to choose $a_n=\cdots = a_1=a_0=[m]_{\text{mod }p}$ for each $n$ as the maps in our inverse system are just the identity on $A$. In particular, given any coherent sequence $(a_n)$ it is determined by the element $a_0$. Thus, $$\lim_{\longleftarrow} A/p^nA\cong A$$ via the isomorphism $(a_n)\mapsto a_o$.